# How can I use Bindings correctly for my ListBox to use radiobuttons choice for every Item individually?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a ListBox in WPF and I'm a beginner in Binding stuff. At first in my Program, I chose with a separate checkbox the choice for my Program. I have an **IF statement** when my checkbox is checked. But now what I want to change is that I have a checkbox for every ListBoxItem, so that I can decide for each Item for itself. For that, I have this ListBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="15,20,10,15" MinHeight="25" Name="tbxFiles"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock x:Name="ListText" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1"  Content="TF"  />
                                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="2"  Content="AF" />
                                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Text="Periode"  />
                                            <Button Grid.Column="4"  Click="RemoveMark_Click"  Content="Delete" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>
                </ListBox>
```

At the end, I want at the point where I ask with an IF statement which checkbox is checked (the checkbox I placed outside of the ListBox). Now, I want to ask with an IF statement "Which checkbox from this ListBoxItem is checked?".

Comment: What is the date type of each of your ListBoxItems?  Is it just a string, or a class that you created?

Comment: The type are just strings

Comment: Then you will need to create a class that contains the string name, and a bool property to hold the checkbox state.  I'll write up an answer to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which ListBoxItem was selected, then you cannot have the ListBoxItems be simple strings.  They must contain a boolean property to track whether or not they were checked.

The simplest way to do this is to convert your string names into a class that holds the string name, and a bool. Like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

But if you want it to work as a Binding, then you will have to implement an MVVM pattern, or a simple INotifyPropertyChanged so that it can detect when the value changes.  Like this:

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string name;
    private bool selected;

    public string Name 
    { 
        get => name; 
        set { name = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); } 
    }
    public bool Selected 
    { 
        get => selected; 
        set { selected = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected")); } 
    }
}
```

**Here is a working example, using the above `Item` class.**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Content="Which ListBoxItems are checked?" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="resultTextBox"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item" + i });
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find out which Items are checked.
        var checkedItems = Items.Where(o => o.Selected).Select(o => o.Name);
        resultTextBox.Text = "These items are checked: " + string.Join(",", checkedItems);
    }
}
```

If you compile and run, here is an example output.  When you click the button that says "Which ListBoxItems are checked?", it will update on the screen which ones are checked!

[image]

Comment: This Code shows me how to do it when I add the Items like that, but I added my Items with an OpenFileDialog and I tried to change that Code to get this with my OpenFileDialog working but i didnt find an way

Comment: @Que, it's impossible to help you if you don't show any of your code.  Please consider opening a new question, show your code, state what you want it to do, and show how your code isn't doing what you want it to do.  If you post a minimal reproducible sample, it makes it easier to guide you in the right direction.